# How to make only one point label visible for QLineSeries/QXYSeries

Tags: c++, qt, qtcharts

I am using the [qtcharts](/questions/tagged/qtcharts) module of [qt](/questions/tagged/qt).
*I am using [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) but it does not matter if the solution comes for another language (I will translate it afterwards).*

**Problem:** I plot a bunch of `QLineSeries` in a `QChart` and I want to display the point labels only when hovering them.

I planned to use the signal [`QXYSeries::hovered()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxyseries.html#hovered) to detect when the mouse moves over a point (the same when the mouse moves away the point).

I know that there exists a member function [`QXYSeries::setPointLabelsVisible()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxyseries.html#pointLabelsVisible-prop) but it makes visible all the points of the series.

I want to be able to display only one point at a time because the series are relatively large and displaying all the labels would degrade the readability.

**Question:** Is it possible to display only one point label for a `QLineSeries` ? If yes, how ?
I could not find such a feature anywhere in the Qt documentation.

---

Here is a baseline code sample to start with (for convenience):

*Declaration*:

```
#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        MainWindow();
};
```

*Definition*:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLineSeries>
#include <QDateTimeAxis>
#include <QValueAxis>
#include <QChartView>
#include <QDateTime>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return app.exec();
}

MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    setWindowTitle("QtCharts baseline");
    resize(800, 500);

    QtCharts::QChart * chart = new QtCharts::QChart;
    chart->setTitle("Baseline sample");
    chart->legend()->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight);

    QtCharts::QDateTimeAxis * time_axis = new QtCharts::QDateTimeAxis;
    time_axis->setFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    time_axis->setTitleText("Time");
    time_axis->setTickCount(5);

    QtCharts::QValueAxis * value_axis = new QtCharts::QValueAxis;
    value_axis->setTitleText("Value (unit)");
    value_axis->setTickCount(6);

    chart->addAxis(time_axis, Qt::AlignBottom);
    chart->addAxis(value_axis, Qt::AlignLeft);

    QtCharts::QLineSeries * ls = new QtCharts::QLineSeries;
    ls->setName("Test series");
    ls->setPointsVisible(true);
    //ls->setPointLabelsVisible(true);

    QDateTime dt = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
    ls->append(dt.toMSecsSinceEpoch(), -10);
    ls->append(dt.addSecs(1).toMSecsSinceEpoch(), 8);
    ls->append(dt.addSecs(2).toMSecsSinceEpoch(), 27);
    ls->append(dt.addSecs(3).toMSecsSinceEpoch(), 12);
    ls->append(dt.addSecs(4).toMSecsSinceEpoch(), 42);
    chart->addSeries(ls);
    ls->attachAxis(time_axis);
    ls->attachAxis(value_axis);

    QtCharts::QChartView * view = new QtCharts::QChartView;
    view->setChart(chart);
    this->setCentralWidget(view);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One technique you could try is making a "shadow" copy of the line series with just the one or few points you need, sitting on top of the actual data line. Draw with a transparent pen so the line doesn't show up but set the labels to be visible. You can add/remove/change points to the shadow copy of the line series, and only the labels you want drawn can be added to the series. The link shows one
[example of the technique.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHNxx.png)

Comment: This would be a decent workaround indeed but I was more interested to find if it was possible to extend the `QLineSeries` capabilites instead (and thus avoid the noise to create this filtered copy). The reason behind is that I have a lot of series to show and I would prefer to avoid the overhead of managing filtered copies for each. But thank you for your answer, I really appreciate it (I didn't even thought of this trick).

Comment: The solution I used is to create an external footer under the chart on which I display the hovered coordinates.