# How to set a custom point labels format for QLineSeries/QXYSeries?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcharts

**Context:** I try to plot a `QLineSeries` on a `QChart` in order to print the progression of a value over time.
Therefore the X axis (abscissa) is a `QDateTimeAxis` and the Y axis (ordinate) is a `QValueAxis`.

**Issue:** I want to display the point labels. But I cannot find how to set the desired format for the datetime.
By default, the labels can only draw the integer values of the point which is what I want for the ordinate value.
But for the abscissa (datetime) value, it prints the number of milliseconds that have passed since the last epoch (*1970-01-01T00:00:00.000*).
I want to change the format for the datetime to match *"hh:mm:ss"* (which is the format I use to display the ticks on the `QDateTimeAxis`).

I know there exists a [`QXYSeries::setPointlabelsFormat()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxyseries.html#pointLabelsFormat-prop) that allows to specify the format but it only accepts the `@xPoint` and `@yPoint` format tags (as you can see in the documentation).

- Here you can find a picture of the issue:
  [image]

As you can see, I can set the format for the `QDateTimeAxis` but not on the points labels.

The code sample that produces this output is based on the one provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58707516/11455384). I just have added more points and uncommented the line `//ls->setPointLabelsVisible(true);`.

**Question:** Is there a way to print `@xPoint` labels with a custom format (ideally to match `QDateTime::toString("hh:mm:ss")`) ? If yes, how ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported by [QXYSeries](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxyseries.html). You can derive a new class from [QAbstractSeries](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractseries.html) for your ***so-called*** `QXYDatetimeSeries` following the same thing implemented by [QXYSeries](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxyseries.html) by reviewing the code. You may also want to change `QXYSeriesPrivate::drawSeriesPointLabels` source code to support your behavior. Don't forget to push your changes to the Qt git repository so that other people can also use it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already have think of that. But I wanted to avoid it if possible. So the answer is no then. I will not modify the source code because it is supposed to be portable and works on other platform (that will obviously not have my modification, unless Qt accepts an eventual pull request). I will draw only the `@yPoint`s instead. When I have time, I'll redefine my own series class.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Soheim, the point label format provided by QtCharts is too limited for this.

If you don't want to get your hands dirty with QtCharts internals, you can solve your problem in another way: Draw the text labels yourself.

Derive a custom graphics item from `QGraphicsObject`:

```
class PointLabelsItem : public QGraphicsObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    PointLabelsItem(QtCharts::QChart *parent = nullptr);
    virtual QRectF boundingRect() const;
    virtual void paint(QPainter*, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem*, QWidget*);

public slots:
    void setRect(const QRectF &area);
    void setAxis(const QAbstractAxis *axis, Qt::Alignment alignment);
    // setter for either source Q*Series or points / point labels

protected:
    QRectF area;
    // const axes*
    // const series* or points/labels
};
```

In the implementation:

```
PointLabelsItem::PointLabelsItem(QtCharts::QChart *parent)
    : QGraphicsObject(parent)
{
    setZValue(10); // put above series
    connect(parent, &QtCharts::QChart::plotAreaChanged,
        this, &PointLabelsItem::setRect);
}

QRectF PointLabelsItem::boundingRect() const
{
    return area;
}

void PointLabelsItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *, QWidget *)
{
    // translate between data coordinates and scene coordinates
    // by making use of `area` and the axes' ranges, OR via
    // qobject_cast<QtCharts::QChart>(parent())->mapToPosition()
    // then draw custom point label texts at the corresp. positions
}

void PointLabelsItem::setRect(const QRectF &newArea)
{
    area = newArea;
    update();
}

void setAxis(const QAbstractAxis *axis, Qt::Alignment alignment)
{
    disconnect(/* old axis member variable */);
    // set corresp. axis member variable here
    connect(axis, &QtCharts::QValueAxis::rangeChanged, this, [this] { update(); });
}
```

From outside:

```
auto pointLabels = new PointLabelsItem(chart);
// set axes, series
```

That's the barebone.

You may also decide to have `QGRaphicsTextItem`s as children of your `PointLabelsItem` (ie., members that have `this` set as their `parent`). This way you can enable user interaction with the labels.

Comment: If I have properly understood, the idea is to draw another `QGraphicsObject` in the `QChart` that will draw the labels independently. Sounds a good workaround. I guess that by `RangeSelectItem` (for the scope in the implementation of `setRect()`) you mean `PointLabelsItem`.

Comment: Sorry that was a copy&paste error. I modified my more specific class for this example.